# Nexus 4 soft keys issue, can I reduce the effective touch screen area on the phone

Tags: xposed-framework

after recent update 4.4.4, my nexus 4 soft keys are not working, after few days, little more area on top of that has went into unusable, is it possible by an xposed module to reduce the effective tough screen area on the phone to only the working touch screen area.